# PyGame not displaying window (MacOS Catalina)

Tags: python, pygame

I recently have fell in love with Python, and have tried to dive into the game development field. So I started off with PyGame. However, upon trying to create the most basic of things, my program fails to run.

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

pygame.init()


window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame game")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
    pygame.display.update()
```

My purpose here, is simple. Create a window, and check to see if the user has hit the cancel, or QUIT button. When I run those code, I don't even get a window. I see the process is running, and I see the the python icon bouncing up and down on my dock bar. I have to force close the python application, but it is not a pygame application. I have seen multiple tutorials, and their code seems to work fine.

Comment: My window was behind another window, maybe look around for it. The code worked

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use infinite loops with any GUI program

Comment: @cricket_007 The aforementioned loop is the game loop, which makes the game, a game.

Comment: @oppressionslayer Hm... Hasn't worked for me

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the code... Maybe the `from pygame import *` caused some sort of error? Or maybe your python version is not compatible with your pygame version?

Comment: Your problem is using pygame on MacOS. If you search a bit on SO for pygame+macos, you'll find a lot of questions with exactly this problem.

Answer (score -1):

There is no visible problem in this code you presented, however, when you are trying to exit from your window, the pygame window will remain. Why? Because you forgot to include `pygame.quit()` after you break out of your game loop. Without this line, your window will persist until you restarted your shell or you rerun your code.

Here is how you do it:

```py
import pygame
from pygame import *

pygame.init()


window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Pygame game")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit() #Just add this line here
```